# Can anyone help with me how to train new data with already saved pickle file?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, machine-learning-model, pickle

**Can anyone help me with the code me to train new data with already saved pickle file?**

I've trained the model with RandomForestClassifier from sklearn and saved the model into .pickle
Now I'm trying to retrain the model on new data with same features. I want to use pickle file to train one new data. Can anyone help me with this in terms of code?

Answer (score 1):

Load the pickle file and your new data. Fit the loaded model on the data

```
model = pickle.load(open(pickle_file,'rb'))
model.fit(x_new, y_new)
```

Comment: This will fit the model from 0 right? Is there a possible way to just make an update with new data? I think in RF it doesn't exist this function.

Comment: No Alex. The saved pickle model is trained. By "fit" in second line you will update training with new data actually.

Comment: Hi @Kasra! I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060432/incremental-training-of-random-forest-model-using-python-sklearn). I think it's not possible to "retrain" a Random Forest. Your code will train a new model, or at least this it  what I understand from the link provided. One option can be use `warm_start`. But it won't retrain, it will just add extra estimators/trees.

Comment: We have to retrain with the new data. That's the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just simply create a new model. What is the problem with it?!

Comment: I'm trying to retrain because the pickle file will store recent trained data and the upcoming data